# How to better design class structure for this code

Tags: java, class, oop

I am making a data structure called `Scalar`. The interface declares what operations are available(like multiply/divide/add/subtract). Anyways i have 3 different classes that implements `Scalar`. A `FractionalScalar` that is represented by a numerator and denominator and a `GeneralScalar` that is represented by a string.

Normally i would add an accessor to the `Scalar` interface like `double get()`.
So I could do stuff like

```
    public class FractionalScalar implements Scalar
    {    

        public Scalar multiply(Scalar other)
        {
            return new FractionalScalar(this.get() * other.get());
        }
        .... // other methods
    }
```

but this only works because a FractionalScalar could be represented by double. The "GeneralScalar" cant be represented by a numeric value because it is supposed to be a theoretical value. Not sure theoretical is the best word but here is what i meant.

```
Scalar a = GeneralScalar('a');
Scalar b = GeneralScalar('b'); 
Scalar one = SimpleScalar(1); 
// this is another class the extends FractionalScalar and is used to represent integers 
Scalar two = SimpleScalar(2);
```

so if i want to represent 2a it would be two.multiply(a);

The thing im doing is supposedly be able to conduct\validate\represent mathematical proofs.

but since GeneralScalar doesnt have a value i have to do something like this

```
public class FractionalScalar implements Scalar
{
    Scalar multiply(Scalar other)
    {
      if (other instanceof FractionalScalar)
      {
           return new FractionalScalar (this.get() * (FractionalScalar) other.get());
      }
      else if (other instanceof GeneralScalar)
      {
            //cast it to generalScalar and do stuff
      }
    }......
}
```

I dont really like  the instanceof if then clauses so is there any better way to do what i am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you post your `GeneralScaler`?.. Also, show your fields please? Does `GeneralScalar` implement `Scalar`

Comment: sorry it should be easier to read now...

Answer (score 2):

You would like to have full dynamic dispatch but Java only does dynamic dispatcher on the instance, not the arguments.

One way to get rid of the `instanceof` is by throwing an exception in `get()` when the scalar cannot compute a value. You would either produce a `FractionalScalar` or, in the presence of an exception, a `GeneralScalar` regardless of the type of scalar. Obviously it would be desirable to have a method like `hasValue()`, in `Scalar`, to avoid generating the exception.